# Possible memory issue or something else?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct, bin

I have been working on a series of tasks involving structs, reading and writing bin files in c.

The struct definition is:

```
struct Data{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned short b;
    short c;
    char d[8];
    short e;
    int f;
    int g;
    short h; 
    char i;
    char j;
    unsigned long k;
    char l;
    double m;
    float n;
    int o;
    char p;
    double q;
}
```

My reading and printing program seems to be working fine, the code is:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    // Check correct number of args
    FILE *record = fopen(argv[1], "r")
    // More Prelim checks

    struct Data entry;

    /* if first field exists, task assumption is that all other fields
     *   must also exist with the proper sizes.
     */
    while(fread(&entry.a, sizeof entry.a, 1, record) > 0){
        fread(&entry.b, sizeof entry.b, 1, record);
        // ... read all fields one by one
        fread(&entry.q, sizeof entry.q, 1, record);
        printf("%u, %d, %d, %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %c, %lu, %hhx, %f, %f, %d, %d, %f", 
                entry.a, entry.b, entry.c . . . entry.q);
    }
}
```

This prints out the input bin file without error (tested automatically against 15 files, some with tens of entries). The simplest one, which is just one entry, is [image]

However, when I try to store ALL the data so that they can be sorted, using the following array, the data starts off correctly, but then goes completely haywire as far as I can see:

```
    struct Data *entries = NULL;
    int curEntries = 100;
    int counter = 1;
    entries = (struct Data *) malloc(curEntries * sizeof(struct Data));
    while(fread(&entries[counter - 1].a, sizeof entries[counter - 1].a, 1, record) >0){
        /* Same reading, storing and printing as above, then increment counter */
    }
```

[image]

Since the reading and the printing parts are EXACTLY the same, other than the use of the "counter" variable, is my problem here something to do with the array memory, and what do I need to fix?

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the non-working program. Remember to also show us your `#include`.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] exposing the problem. One approach for MCVE would be to simplify the struct (much less fields).

Comment: I also recommend reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learning how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Furthermore you might consider using some tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect memory and pointer problems.

Comment: Meaningful member names make following code much easier. Surely it isn't hard to be more creative than `a-q`?

Comment: By the way, why initialize `counter` to `1` and use `counter - 1` all over? Why not simply initialize it to `0`?

Comment: I'll try, but it seems like the problem only occurs at a specific point (the 12th field, the one after the unsigned long). Everything after that screws up.

And I have names like fish, cat and so on as part of the specification, but they didn't actually mean anything so for posting my code up I thought, just in case of confusion, I'd keep it simple. The variable names have nothing to do with what types of data they are storing

Comment: I thought about initialising to 0, and I almost did, but it didn't matter to me too much. I'm also using the counter to double array size if necessary, so I would have had to +1 or -1 somewhere anyway.

Initialising to 0 IS probably the better option though

Comment: Initializing to zero would make the rest of the code simpler, and with simpler code it's harder to make mistakes. Even if you need to have a `+1` or a `-1` somewhere it's only *once* (or twice or some such) not 17 or more times.

Comment: Have you considered possibility that binary file is corrupted?

Comment: Can we have a look at the writing code? (if it is yours)

Comment: Your issue starts with the 10th element. Maybe show us that specific read line?

Comment: Are you reading the same file in both cases? If yes, that this may be due to allignement within the struct. You shall write and read the file with the same method or try packed structure.

Comment: Is the size of the binary file a multiple of 60?

Comment: Maybe include the code you summarize as "/* Same reading, storing and printing as above, then increment counter */"?  It would presumably not be identical to the code above, as it would have to access the entry in the array.  Since the code is not identical, perhaps the bug is in the code you have omitted.

Comment: Plus: remove the cast of mallocs return value and `#include <stdlib.h>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Your comments on debugging really helped me solve this problem, especially those who commented about the reading and format.
As it turned out, I did need to change it slightly, and now my code runs, so thanks :)

@ joop uh, i have that library lol
does that mean I don't have to cast?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: SOLVED.
The implementation was correct, but many of these comments about formatting and
use of variables are extremely helpful. 
The issue was a difference in format that I had to code for.